# How to update rows in SQL database using SQLAlchemy and pandas (simple way)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use df.to_sql() in a way it only replaces values available in df it's called on without **scraping** the whole table as it happens when you pass 'if_exists=replace'?

I've seen examples with convoluted code, sessionmakers, etc. like in the below examples:

[How to update SQLAlchemy row entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry)

[Updating specific row in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134439/updating-specific-row-in-sqlalchemy)

[Updating row in SqlAlchemy ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307238/updating-row-in-sqlalchemy-orm)

but it's too convoluted. Following an example on SQLAlchemy I tried:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Update

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import update, table, column, select, text
update(table('tbl_plans')).where("portfolio_id_host=='TESTING'").values(portfolio_id_host='Tested')
```

but all it produces is:

```
<sqlalchemy.sql.dml.Update object at 0x00000193C18F8630>
```

and no actual update is made.

Using .to_sql() on df with only rows I want to update drops the existing table, creates new one, inserts rows. Is there an elegant / efficient way to do **update** just what I need? (by update I don't mean, delete, create, insert) but actual UPDATE SQL equivalent

Answer (score 2):

`sqlalchemy.sql.update` generates an object representing an update statement without executing it.

To use it, you have to run `Connection.execute()`

[See the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes)